# Array association and DB design

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a shopping cart sort of DB, where users can checkout certain items and I would be able to see what items each person has and I would also be able to see who a specific item is checked out to.
I would also like to have an image for each item. (not sure how efficient that is?)

Currently I have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
id CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE items(
id CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
itemName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
category VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
subcategory VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
image LONGBLOB
);

CREATE TABLE person_items(
personID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
itemID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES person(id),
FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES items(id)
);
```

Is this an efficient way to basically store an array of items that a person is allowed to check out, or are there better ways?
Also, is storing a `LONGBLOB` for an image a good idea or is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your IDs in your tables should be INTEGERs. The relation table 'person_items' enables a n:m relation between person and items, which should be your goal, if I understood your question.

I suggest to save a path and the image file name in your db, so that you can get this value and use it as link or something similar in your app. I would not save the image as a blob cause you have a lot of unneccesary work with headers and so on. And if using a path in the db, you will easily be able to use different file formats. Just my opinion.

Comment: You could store the type or even the file name in the table as well, along with the blob. But a good reason to not store images in a database I've learned over the years that your database backup becomes very large, and this makes it harder to make backups and also to setup test environments. By keeping the files separate, you can use good database tools to backup the database, and good file backup tools to backup the files.